# Why does LinqPad run ToString() on some types when they are dumped?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I'm using `NuGetVersion` from the `NuGet.Versioning` package in LinqPad.  I'm trying to `Dump()` it to inspect it's properties, but instead of the usual dump I just get the string representation.

For example, this:

```
var v = new NuGetVersion("1.0.0");
v.Dump();
```

Shows the following in the output window:

```
1.0.0
```

Does anyone know why LinqPad runs `ToString()` when some types are dumped, and how to change this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure that is not the only public property? I think `Dump()` just dumps public properties for objects not inheriting from a well known type.

Comment: Yes, it has a few public properties.  The source is here: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/NuGetVersion.cs

Comment: I think only [Joe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46223/joe-albahari) can answer this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, LINQPad calls `ToString()` rather than expanding the properties if the object implements `System.IFormattable`.

You could override this by writing an extension method in **My Extensions** that uses LINQPad's [ICustomMemberProvider](http://www.linqpad.net/faq.aspx#extensibility):

**EDIT:** There's now an easier way. Call LINQPad's `Util.ToExpando()` method:

```
var v = new NuGetVersion("1.0.0");
Util.ToExpando (v).Dump();
```

(Util.ToExpando converts the object into an ExpandoObject.)

For reference, here's the old solution that utilizes ICustomMemberProivder:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static object ForceExpand<T> (this T value)
        => value == null ? null : new Expanded<T> (value);

    class Expanded<T> : ICustomMemberProvider
    {
        object _instance;
        PropertyInfo[] _props;

        public Expanded (object instance)
        {
            _instance = instance;
            _props = _instance.GetType().GetProperties();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetNames() => _props.Select (p => p.Name);
        public IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes () => _props.Select (p => p.PropertyType);
        public IEnumerable<object> GetValues () => _props.Select (p => p.GetValue (_instance));
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
new NuGetVersion("1.2.3.4").ForceExpand().Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks Joe.  Would you consider adding an overload to do this?  Something like `v.Dump(forceExpand: true);`?

Comment: The advantage of a ForceExpand() method like the one above over a Dump overload is that it can be specified on individual properties.

Comment: Note that `ICustomMemberProvider` isn't documented at that link any longer.